# When is the direct image functor exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Consider a morphism of topological spaces $f:X\to Y$. The direct image functor takes a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ to the sheaf defined by $f_*\mathcal{F}(U)=\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(U))$. It's a right adjoint to the inverse image functor, which means it is automatically left-exact (but usually not right exact).

Here are some general situations I know when $f_*$ is exact:

1) $f$ is a closed immersion (true for any mapping of topological spaces, not just schemes)

2) $f$ is affine and we consider quasicoherent sheaves (a generalization of 1, but this time requiring $X,Y$ be schemes and the sheaves quasicoherent)

and then my knowledge of this situation kind of teeters off in to the distance.

**Question**: What are some more scenarios where we know that $f_*$ is exact (are there any)? I'm curious about what adjectives one can stick on $X,Y,f$ which would let me know without extra calculation that $f_*$ is exact. I'm mostly concerned with $X,Y$ schemes, I'm somewhat interested in the case where $X,Y$ are analytic spaces over any of $\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$, and I'd definitely take other interesting scenarios if any of you want to tell me about them.

Comment: For the case of schemes I think $f$ affine is necessary and sufficient; this would be a relative version of Serre's criterion.

Comment: For the case $f$ affine, shouldn't we restrict ourselves to the category of quasi-coherent sheaves ? I thought $R^if_*\mathcal{F}=0$ for $i>0$ was true only when $\mathcal{F}$ was quasi-coherent.

Comment: Does it work for f being quasi-compact and separate for quasi-coherent sheaves?

Comment: For 2), I don't think this is true in general (or please enlighten me).  What you mean is that if $X$ and $Y$ are schemes and $f$ is affine, then $f_\ast \colon \mathrm{QCoh}(X) \to \mathrm{QCoh}(Y)$ is an exact functor.